# How do I parse http html post data submitted by a form

Tags: python, html, http

So I have an html form like below:

```
<form action='/Login/Process' method='post'>
        Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="Username">
        <br>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="password" name="Password"><br>
        Keep me logged in:<br>
        <input type="text" name="KeepSessionAlive"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I would like Python to receive the data (That part is done) then  process it into a dictionary for future use. I have attempted to use the code below but it doesn't work with more than two post fields and even then it is kind of spotty.

```
import re
import Vars
def RECV_Post():
        Vars.RECV_Post=dict(re.findall(r"(?P<name>.*?)=(?P<value>.*?)&", Vars.RECV_Data))
        Vars.RECV_Post.update(re.findall(r"&(?P<name>.*?)=(?P<value>.*)&", Vars.RECV_Data))
        Vars.RECV_Post.update(re.findall(r"&(?P<name>.*?)=(?P<value>.*)", Vars.RECV_Data))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's ALL you're doing, raw CGI will be simple enough.

```
import cgi

DATA = cgi.FieldStorage()

d = {}

for attr in DATA.keys():
    key = str(attr)
    value = DATA['key'].value
    d[key] = value
```

Comment: I would rather be using re instead because im already importing it for other things and want to keep the code as simple as possible

Comment: Importing another module doesn't hurt, and what I put it about as simple as it gets.